# How do I resolve this warning issue in Prettier?

Tags: prettier

I am currently running Visual Studio Code on an Ubuntu dual boot. I am trying to get the Prettier extension to work but it seems I have no luck. It is installed but when I try to save and format my code the editor does nothing and I get a warning sign instead.

I have tired to solve this by:

Setting Prettier as my Default Formatter.
Editing the Json file.
Uninstalling and Reinstalling.

Not only that I keep getting this Error:

{
"ignored": false,
"inferredParser": "json"
}
["INFO" - 1:50:05 AM] No local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig) detected, falling back to VS Code configuration

If anyone can help I would be deeply grateful.

Answer (score -1):

in vs code , go to extensions(ctr + shift + X) then check "ESLint" , if it is installed please uninstall and try